# Deadlock via simultaneously executing UPDATE statements on a single table on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock

I've found this SO question: [SQL Server deadlock between two update statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640458/sql-server-deadlock-between-two-update-statements) that tell us that author run into the deadlock just simultaneously executing simple UPDATE statements ***on a single table*** like this:

```
update a
set some_column = 'somewhat',
    fk = 42 -- this is FK constraint to another table
where id = 1 -- PK
```

We're assuming that it's the only executing kind of statements, there are not triggers or jobs.

I've tried variety of cases, but was not able to reproduce it.

Is it ever possible? Please, provide a code sample.

**UPDATE:** My code sample that does NOT reproduce the issue:

Setup code:

```
-- create tables
create table B
(
    id int primary key
)

create table A
(
    id int primary key,
    b_id int not null,
    int_field int
    foreign key (b_id) references B(id)
)

go

-- add some data
declare @i int = 0

while @i < 1000
begin
    insert into B
    values (@i)

    insert into A
    values (@i, @i, @i)

    set @i = @i + 1
end
```

Workers' code (run in at least two sessions simultaneously):

```
while 1=1
    update A
    set int_field = 1,
        b_id = ROUND(999 * RAND(), 0)
    where id = ROUND(999 * RAND(), 0)
```

Comment: What cases did you try, exactly? It's certainly possible to achieve a deadlock if you run 2 statements that access the same tables, but in different order. (I.e. query 1 updates table A referencing table B, Query 2 updates B referencing A). If you're unable to reproduce the behaviour, it might simply indicate that the tables the user from the original question uses simply contain more data.

Comment: @SchmitzIT, I've added code sample for you

Comment: @SchmitzIT, I meant that table A is the only table that we're updating.